# Cisco nexus 3048 SFP validation failed

Tags: cisco, switch, network, cisco-nexus

I have cisco Nexus 3048TP switch (48x1G + 4x10G)

```
Hardware
  cisco Nexus 3048 Chassis ("48x1GE + 4x10G Supervisor")
  Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU        P4505  @ 1.87GHz with 3665240 kB of memory.
  Processor Board ID FOC17237JKC
```

I am seeing this error on port `e1/49` which is 10G port and i have connected 10G SFP+ transceiver

```
 Ethernet1/49 is down (SFP validation failed)
     Dedicated Interface
      Hardware: 1000/10000 Ethernet, address: f872.eaae.36b8 (bia f872.eaae.36b8)
      MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec
      reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
      Encapsulation ARPA
      Port mode is access
      auto-duplex, 10 Gb/s, media type is 10G
```

As per documentation they said you need to set `speed` so i did and got this error

```
n3k(config)# int e1/49
n3k(config-if)# speed 10000
ERROR: Ethernet1/49: Configuration does not match the port capability.
```

Interface capability

```
n3k# sh int e1/49 capabilities
Ethernet1/49
  Model:                 N3K-C3048TP-1GE-SUP
  Type (SFP capable):    Unknown Type-(unknown)
  Speed:                 10000
  Duplex:                full
  Trunk encap. type:     802.1Q
  Channel:               yes
  Broadcast suppression: percentage(0-100)
  Flowcontrol:           rx-(off/on),tx-(off/on)
  Rate mode:             none
  QOS scheduling:        rx-(6q1t),tx-(1p6q0t)
  CoS rewrite:           no
  ToS rewrite:           no
  SPAN:                  yes
  UDLD:                  yes
  MDIX:                  no
  Link Debounce:         yes
  Link Debounce Time:    yes
  Pvlan Trunk capable:   no
  TDR capable:           no
  FabricPath capable:    no
  Port mode:             Routed,Switched
  FEX Fabric:            no
```

This switch located in remote datacenter so i can't re-seed until i have resources available, is there anything else i can do remotely?

Comment: What kind of SPF is in the port?

Comment: FS  https://www.fs.com/products/11552.html I have 5000 SFP running in datacenter on all kind of hardware also i have same model of switch in other datacenter and that running fine with same model of SFP, I can guarantee its not SFP+ issue.. its something related to configuration

Comment: Sixteen dollars?  You get what you pay for, Satish.

Comment: It could certainly be a bad SFP, or you have a different hardware or software version in the switch that simply rejects this SFP..

Comment: Believe me we have 50 nexus switches and 5 ASR routes and all running on same SFP+ and they all fine.. even my other datacenter has Nexus 3048 switch running on same model of SFP.. do you still this it's SFP issue?  I have working switch on same model

Comment: @RonMaupin its not BAD SFP because i have 4 switch and its show same result on all 4 switches.

Comment: There can be subtle differences in the hardware of switches that were produced at different times, and there is other firmware in the device (bootloader, etc.) than the NXOS it is running. All of which can matter to something like this.

Comment: If the correct Cisco part works in the SFP+ slot, then the switch is fine, and it simply rejects that particular SFP+.

Comment: I can say its 100% configuration issue or firmware upgrade, i trust 100% on these SFP+ because last 6 years we are using them and never heard any compatibility issue or any kind of failure.. Let me dig more.. and see..

Comment: I remember a few years ago when the ASRs we were using changed a bit, and the WAN cards we were using would no longer work in the newer ASRs. Cisco had a new lead-free solder for the WAN cards that required an IOS-XE upgrade, so we had to buy different WAN cards and run a new IOS-XE because of the subtle hardware change in the new ASRs of the same model. It may be that from now on, you cannot use those SFP+ modules in those switches.

Comment: This is interesting... https://www.cocheno.com/2017/05/sfp-validation-failed-on-nexus/ but not working in my case.. look like i have to remove SFP physically and then set speed

Comment: @RonMaupin not sure about your ASR (SFP) issue but i am very confident on these (FS) SFP because i have all kind of  hardware, (Cisco, Dell, HP, Mikrotik, SAN storage and i am exclusively using these SFP even i had Cisco SFP on some of switch and i had 1% failure on them even spending tons of money, Last year i have order 10,000 SFP from same model and running everywhere starting from server to edge router and had no issue at all, FS is one of best company i have found so far in fiber technology.. by the way i am not promoting them here :) just telling my story.

Comment: The ASR thing we ran into wasn't SFPs, it was WAN cards. The whole lead-free thing apparently messed with a lot of stuff, but it was only the WAN cards for us. Cisco had to make changes to the ASR hardware to accomodate the lead-free cards, then the other cards wouldn't work, and the lead-free cards required an IOS-XE upgrade. You need to watch out for stuff like that.

Comment: Try setting the speed to 1000 and see if the switch recognizes the SFP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solved:

After reboot switch it fixed my issue, Now its showing `SFP Type 10Gbase-SR`

```
n3k# show int e1/49 capabilities
Ethernet1/49
  Model:                 N3K-C3048TP-1GE-SUP
  Type (SFP capable):    10Gbase-SR
  Speed:                 10000
  Duplex:                full
  Trunk encap. type:     802.1Q
  Channel:               yes
```

Look like you need to set `speed` first before inserting SFP.

Quote from cisco documentation:

[image]